# excel - Merge two excel files with similar columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have to excel tables that I want to merge, my second table have some of the columns that I have in the first table but not all of them and not is the dame order.

for example:

The first excel,    the 2nd excel

## status  Model    cost      #  status cost        MOoel   linesatatus

1  gol      ds    20$          1   tes1     20$      XXS     no
2  gol        ds  30$          3   tes3     30$     SSS      yes
3  gol       ds    40$         4   tes4              SSs     no
4  gol       ds   50$

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576)
2. Copy paste values only from the combined pivot so that you can
3. Manually add as much data as you want to the new table

If that does not work use, if you don't mind uploading your files to an online service, for example http://www.gridoc.com/combine-tables and merge the tables using drag&drop or the add-on [PowerQuery](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/merge-queries-HA104149757.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872)

Comment: it's a large file that i need to do a lot with and i"m adding a lot of data manually after i have all the data in one table, is there any way to do that without pivot?

Comment: i trying to write a vba fot this, i did it for 1 coloumn: `Sheets("ments").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AR$4832").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Global"
    Range("d3:d" & cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Report").Select
    Range("f" & cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste` . Is there any easier way to do that for all column (i have the same header in both tables)?

Comment: I can't comment on the code, but please try the 3 steps above (pivot, unpivot, add your data)

Comment: I would suggest using an add-on or an online service for data merging (see ans for links)